# Angular2 RC5 Fusion Charts with routing not working because of base href tag

Tags: svg, angular, fusioncharts

I am using Angular2 rc5 with routing, So in `index.html` I wrote

```
document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />')
```

I am using fusion charts in my app.

I have 2 charts in following url in components

`/fusion1`   chart here works properly default url for app

and when I click on link the url becomes now

`/fusion2` here chart won't render properly it displays labels but wont render palette colors.

If we see fill url in svg it displays like this

```
fill=url('localhost:8443/fusion1#588xr___120_278_216__rgba_0_174_141_1_:0-rgba_0_174_141_1_:100')
```

My fill url is not taking updated route url which has to take

localhost:8443/fusion2

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Answered a similar question forAAngular 7 here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25713345/fusioncharts-not-rendering-properly-when-base-tag-included-in-html-head

Answer (score 1):

Provide `APP_BASE_HREF` instead of the `<base>` tag to configure the router, then you can set `<base href="...">` independent of the router.

```
providers: [{provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/'}]
```

See also [Angular 2 router no base href set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34535163/angular-2-router-no-base-href-set)

Comment: hello thanks for your reply, I have made changes, but still fill url is not taking the latest url routed. fill=url('localhost:8443/fusion1#588xr___120_278_216__rgba_0_174_141_1_:0-rgba_0_174_141_1_:100') , it is taking fusion1 page url only.