# What's the difference between --base-href and --deploy-url parameters of angular-cli tool

Tags: angular, angular-cli

The documentation of Angular informs one should use `--base-href` parameter in the Angular application build for production when it's going to be deployed in a subfolder:

> If you copy the files into a server sub-folder, append the build flag,
> `--base-href` and set the `<base href>` appropriately.
>
> For example, if the `index.html` is on the server at `/my/app/index.html`,
> set the base href to `<base href="/my/app/">` like this.

https://angular.io/guide/deployment

However, the angular-cli has the `--deploy-url` parameter. The documentation of the tool describes it as:

> URL where files will be deployed.

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build

I have seen solutions that use the `--deploy-url` instead of `--base-href` when the application is going to be deployed in a subfolder.

#The question#

What's the difference between `--base-href` and `--deploy-url` parameters of angular-cli tool? When should I use each one?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The answers here are not completely accurate, outdated, and do not give a full explanation.

> When should I use each one?

**tl;dr** In general use `--base-href`, because `--deploy-url`

1. is deprecated as of Angular v13
2. will decrease build speed (although, probably not too significant)
3. does not have the benefits of `base href` in ["locating relative template (HTML) assets, and relative fetch/XMLHttpRequests."](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#the-deploy-url)

If you need the URL to be different than where the assets are placed, the [official documentation](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#the-deploy-url) recommends setting `APP_BASE_HREF` manually (and differently, e.g. set `--base-href` to `/public/` and `APP_BASE_HREF` to `/users/` if you will serve the Angular files at https://example.com/public/ but you want the web app's URL to be https://example.com/users/)

> What's the difference between `--base-href` and `--deploy-url` parameters of angular-cli tool?

Above I've already listed 3 differences.

As you have already stated in your question, `--base-href` sets the `<base href>` in the `index.html` (for details see the [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base) and for implications see the [community wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889076/what-are-the-recommendations-for-html-base-tag)), while `--deploy-url` prefixes the relative links inside the `index.html` file.

For example, the following `index.html` snippet:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.HASH.css">
...
<script src="main.HASH.js" type="module"></script>
```

With `--deploy-url /public/`, will be outputted as:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/styles.HASH.css">
...
<script src="/public/main.HASH.js" type="module"></script>
```

`--deploy-url` seems to literally just prefix the links, so if you instead did `--deploy-url public`, the output would be pretty much unusable:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="publicstyles.HASH.css">
...
<script src="publicmain.HASH.js" type="module"></script>
```

Lastly, if you have a template (HTML) that uses a relative link to an asset, e.g. a `header.component.html` that contains `<img src="assets/logo.jpg">`, but you use `--deploy-url /public/`, the link will not be prefixed and will give you a broken image. This would instead work if `<base href="/public/">` is set using `--base-href /public/`.

Answer (score 137):

- **Base-href** is being used by routing
- **deploy-url** is for assets.

In most cases base-href is enough.

Please see these posts:

- https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9835
- https://shekhargulati.com/2017/07/06/angular-4-use-of-base-href-and-deploy-url-build-options/

Comment: tldr; See the accepted answer below https://stackoverflow.com/a/70575325/9807140

Although this is the highest voted comment, it is out of date as deploy-url is deprecated https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/commit/e95ecb8ab0382eb803741619c446d6cc7b215ba0

Answer (score 54):

To put my scripts inside the "**/test/app1/script/**" folder, I use this [command](https://shekhargulati.com/2017/07/06/angular-4-use-of-base-href-and-deploy-url-build-options/):

```
ng build --prod --base-href /test/app1/ --deploy-url /test/app1/script/
```

Thus my app is accessible at https://example.com/test/app1/ but my JS scripts and CSS are in the https://example.com/test/app1/script/ directory.

Comment: This is a great answer, but be warned that it can effect lazy loading of modules. E.g.: 
 `{ path: 'myModule', loadChildren: () => import( './myModule/my.module' ).then( m => m.MyModule ) }`

Answer (score 28):

If I want to use `/users` as my application base for the router and `/public` as a base for my assets,

```
ng build --prod --base-href /users/ --deploy-url /public
```

See [Shekhar Gulati's](https://shekhargulati.com/2017/07/06/angular-4-use-of-base-href-and-deploy-url-build-options/) blog for a detailed example.

Comment: I am following this thread with my similar to this problem. Here is my command: "ng build --watch=true --baseHref=/dist/ --outputPath=D:\application_root\dist --deployUrl=/dist/". What I am trying to say is that run the app from application_root folder, but all the code for the front-end is located in the "dist" sub folder. Also do I have to copy index.html from dist to the root?

Comment: it's `--base-href /users/` and not `--base-href /users`. (missing slash)

Comment: Downvote until critical mistake is fixed. I know the blog doesn't have the terminating slash for `--base-href` but it is crucial according to [official docs](https://angular.io/guide/router#html5-urls-and-the--base-href): _The `<base href>` `path` should end with a "/", as browsers ignore characters in the `path` that follow the right-most "/"._

Answer (score 4):

Migrating from Angular v12 to Angular v14:

**BEFORE v12**

index.html:

```
<base href="/">  // overriden by angular.json
```

package.json:

```
"start": "ng serve --base-href=/my-app/"  // obsolete
```

**AFTER v14**

angular.json:

```
"baseHref": "/"  // used for finding .js files
```

app.module.ts:

```
providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/my-app/' },  // used for routing
```

Specifying `"deployUrl"` in angular.json didn't work for me.

Comment: Hi Victor, about baseHref property, where is this found in the three?

Comment: @Slinker009 it's in angular.json file: projects > your_project_name > architect > build > options > baseHref