# routing in Angular 2 (v6 )

Tags: angular

I am having some issues with the routing in Angular 2 (v6 )

The site is structured like this:

(root, site.com/)

----subfolder1 (site.com/subfolder1)

----subfolder2 (site.com/subfolder2)

----client(site.com/client) << Anuglar Site

When we deploy we are using : ng build --prod --deploy-url=/client/

for some reasom it always goes to PageNotFoundComponent when we navigate to site.com/client/quote/88b02e09-511b-40c5-a64a-a3aeb2b9d239

Ours route param:

> const routes: Routes = [   { path: '', component: QuoteSearchComponent
>   },   { path: 'quote/:guid', component: QuoteComponent },   { path:
>   '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent } ];
>
> main.9a26b5fe0012f4ac3aae.js:1 GuardsCheckEnd(id: 1, url:
>   '/quote/88b02e09-511b-40c5-a64a-a3aeb2b9d239', urlAfterRedirects:
>   '/quote/88b02e09-511b-40c5-a64a-a3aeb2b9d239', state: Route(url:'',
>   path:'') { Route(url:'quote/88b02e09-511b-40c5-a64a-a3aeb2b9d239',
>   path:'quote/:guid') } , shouldActivate: true)
>   main.9a26b5fe0012f4ac3aae.js:1 e {id: 1, url:
>   "/quote/88b02e09-511b-40c5-a64a-a3aeb2b9d239", urlAfterRedirects:
>   "/quote/88b02e09-511b-40c5-a64a-a3aeb2b9d239", state: e,
>   shouldActivate: true} main.9a26b5fe0012f4ac3aae.js:1 Router Event: e
>   main.9a26b5fe0012f4ac3aae.js:1 ResolveStart(id: 1, url:
>   '/quote/88b02e09-511b-40c5-a64a-a3aeb2b9d239', urlAfterRedirects:
>   '/quote/88b02e09-511b-40c5-a64a-a3aeb2b9d239', state: Route(url:'',
>   path:'') { Route(url:'quote/88b02e09-511b-40c5-a64a-a3aeb2b9d239',
>   path:'quote/:guid') } ) main.9a26b5fe0012f4ac3aae.js:1 e {id: 1, url:
>   "/quote/88b02e09-511b-40c5-a64a-a3aeb2b9d239", urlAfterRedirects:
>   "/quote/88b02e09-511b-40c5-a64a-a3aeb2b9d239", state: e}
>   main.9a26b5fe0012f4ac3aae.js:1 Router Event: e
>   main.9a26b5fe0012f4ac3aae.js:1 ResolveEnd(id: 1, url:
>   '/quote/88b02e09-511b-40c5-a64a-a3aeb2b9d239', urlAfterRedirects:
>   '/quote/88b02e09-511b-40c5-a64a-a3aeb2b9d239', state: Route(url:'',
>   path:'') { Route(url:'quote/88b02e09-511b-40c5-a64a-a3aeb2b9d239',
>   path:'quote/:guid') } ) main.9a26b5fe0012f4ac3aae.js:1 e {id: 1, url:
>   "/quote/88b02e09-511b-40c5-a64a-a3aeb2b9d239", urlAfterRedirects:
>   "/quote/88b02e09-511b-40c5-a64a-a3aeb2b9d239", state: e}
>   main.9a26b5fe0012f4ac3aae.js:1 Router Event: t
>   main.9a26b5fe0012f4ac3aae.js:1 ActivationEnd(path: 'quote/:guid')
>   main.9a26b5fe0012f4ac3aae.js:1 t {snapshot: t}
>   main.9a26b5fe0012f4ac3aae.js:1 Router Event: t
>   main.9a26b5fe0012f4ac3aae.js:1 ChildActivationEnd(path: '')
>   main.9a26b5fe0012f4ac3aae.js:1 t {snapshot: t}
>   main.9a26b5fe0012f4ac3aae.js:1 Router Event: e
>   main.9a26b5fe0012f4ac3aae.js:1 NavigationEnd(id: 1, url:
>   '/quote/88b02e09-511b-40c5-a64a-a3aeb2b9d239', urlAfterRedirects:
>   '/quote/88b02e09-511b-40c5-a64a-a3aeb2b9d239')
>   main.9a26b5fe0012f4ac3aae.js:1 e {id: 1, url:
>   "/quote/88b02e09-511b-40c5-a64a-a3aeb2b9d239", urlAfterRedirects:
>   "/quote/88b02e09-511b-40c5-a64a-a3aeb2b9d239"}

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51182322/whats-the-difference-between-base-href-and-deploy-url-parameters-of-angular)

Answer (score 0):

I need more info about what are you trying to do, but check my example out as a guide:

Best practices said you always need to put path values in your statement.

```
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router'
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';
import { AboutComponent  } from './components/about/about.component'
import { HeroesComponent } from './components/heroes/heroes.component'

const APP_ROUTES: Routes = [
    { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},
    { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent},
    { path: 'heroes', component: HeroesComponent},
    { path: '**', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'home'}
]

export const APP_ROUTING = RouterModule.forRoot(APP_ROUTES, { useHash: true });
```