# Angular Deployment assets path

Tags: angular, ng-build

Build project in `Angular7`.
After build through command `ng-build --prod --base-href /client/product/v2/`

> deploy in **vs** folder, but folder structure is : www.domain.com/client/product/vs

All the images are in `assets` folder and after build assets folder is in root.

After deployment, all the `images` path are broken.
some images are `../../imagename.png` and some through css `../imagename.png`.

any idea how to fix this path issue?
TIA

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51185659/236896, this may help you. you should checkout deploy-url property.

Comment: @Manoj, even using `--deploy-url` still facing same issue.

Answer (score 2):

Fast foward to 2022, my problem and solution is as following:

**Wrong way:** using `"../assets/something.png"` or `"../../assets/something.png"` works fine with `ng serve`, but not with `ng build`, like this

```js
    <img src="../assets/something.png>
```

**Right way:** easily using `"asset/someting.png"` works fine with both `ng serve` and `ng build`, like this

```js
    <img src="assets/something.png>
```