# Angular 9 Elements: how to create a standalone WebComponent (with all the dependencies)?

Tags: angular, web-component, angular-elements

I'm trying to design a new application based on **Micro Frontends** with **Angular 9** and **WebComponents**.
The main goal that I want to achieve with WebComponents is tha ability to have different teams working independently, deploying their updates whenever they want and having the main wrapper just download the corresponding self contained bundle and inject it in the wrapping page.

As for now I do not need to handle different frameworks, but I just need to have very **low coupling** between each of them, both on the dependencies (each WebComponent should bring its own dependencies by itself, with the allowed exception of Polyfills and Runtime for the moment) and on the deployments (just deploy/expose the WebComponent bundle and get it injected in the wrapper through a GET API).
The architecture that I have in mind is as follows:

1. **UI**: this is the wrapper for all the other WebComponents
2. **DashboardOne-UI**: a dashboard registered as a WebComponent
3. **DashboardTwo-UI**: a dashboard registered as a WebComponent

The examples of WebComponents that I found on the web are all very basic; I mean they just use standard html elements (buttons, paragraphs, ...), hence no dependency to incorporate in the output bundle.
In my case, DashboardOne-UI relies on **Prime-NG** and **Prime-Icons**, and I would avoid having suche dependencies installed also on the **UI**.

In order to build the DashboardOne-UI and serve the output files, I use **NGX-Build-Plus** and **HTTP-Server** by running the following commands:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "http-server dist/DashboardOne-UI/ --port 8084",
    "build": "ng build --prod --single-bundle"
}
```

After the build, the dist folder contains:

[image]
[image]

and this is the content of **index.html**:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>OrganizationUI</title>
    <base href="/">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  </head>
  <body>
    <organization-dashboard></organization-dashboard>
    <script src="polyfills.js" defer></script>
    <script src="scripts.js" defer></script>
    <script src="polyfill-webcomp-es5.js" defer></script>
    <script src="polyfill-webcomp.js" defer></script>
    <script src="main.js" defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

By running the start script I am able to get the WebComponent working as expected in the browser, but when I inject only the **main.js** script in the **UI** application it fails to get all the fonts and styles:

[image]

The only way I found to avoid having such dependencies on the wrapping **UI**, is to make the **DashboardOne** WebComponent'css point to the styles on **NPM** instead of local **node_modules**, by using:

```
@import url("https://unpkg.com/primeicons@2.0.0/primeicons.css");
@import url("https://unpkg.com/primeng@9.0.0/resources/primeng.min.css");
@import url("https://unpkg.com/primeng@9.0.0/resources/themes/nova-light/theme.css");
@import url("https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.4.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css");
```

instead of:

```
@import url("~primeicons/primeicons.css");
@import url("~primeng/resources/primeng.min.css");
@import url("~primeng/resources/themes/nova-light/theme.css");
@import url("~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css");
```

The problem with this approach is that I need to handle the dependencies in two places, css and package.json.
Is there a better way to build self contained WebComponents in Angular 9, such that I just need to import a single JS file in the wrapping UI application, without caring about WebComponents' dependencies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible approach towards a better solution, I just found, is to provide the

```
ng build
```

with a path for the deploy URL (more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51182322/whats-the-difference-between-base-href-and-deploy-url-parameters-of-angular)):

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "http-server dist/DashboardOne-UI/ --port 8084",
  "build": "ng build --single-bundle --deploy-url http://localhost:8084/"
}
```

By this way, the **DashboardOne-UI** web-component element, once injected in the **UI** wrapper, will point to its own server where all the needed resources can be found.

Comment: Can you share more details on creating web component with angular 9? It will be greatly appreciated.