# Angular app deployment to IIS - Images not displaying (Static URLs)

Tags: angular, image, url, iis, deployment

I am deploying an angular 6 app to IIS. I installed IIS Rewrite module and also updated the web.config file and index.html file with Base URLs and rewrite rules.

Issue is Login page shows up without the logo/images. I tried to see what is wrong.
http://localhost/ATSTV2/#/login (This shows up the login page with controls and without images)

I looked at the image urls referred and it shows up an the source as http://localhost/assets/Logo_White.png which is incorrect. 
The correct image link is http://localhost/ATSTV2/assets/Logo_White.png

Apart from changing my web.config and index.html for base URL, should I make some global changes and ensure the static urls are referred correctly?

This whole application works locally just fine with angular CLI ng serve. But when deploying to server I am deploying it to IIS and hence following some suggested approaches in the internet.

[image: Angular.json snippet]

Comment: Does your routing work otherwise?

Comment: Yes. I am able to navigate using my menu options and other controls display and work fine

Comment: Feel free to post your solution and mark it as an answer so as to help whoever also ran into this issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51182322/whats-the-difference-between-base-href-and-deploy-url-parameters-of-angular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You an use the `deploy-url` option to specify the url from which to load js/css files.

```
ng build ... --deploy-url /ATSTV2/
```

**Edit**

Try modifying `angular.json` file and set `deployUrl : "/ATSTV2/` to projects->YourProjectName->architect->build->options

```
 "projects": {
    "YourProjectName": {
      ...
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            ...
            "deployUrl" : "/ATSTV2/",
```

Comment: Hi David. Deploy url option does not fix the issue

Comment: What's the logo url after that?

Comment: In my page IIS Uses localhost/assets/Logo_White.png as the URL which is incorrect. The correct image link is localhost/ATSTV2/assets/Logo_White.png. I am not sure why IIS uses the url localhost/assets/Logo_White.png  instead of localhost/ATSTV2/assets/Logo_White.png

Comment: @SARAVAN Weird, somewhat the option is ignored. I edited my post, can ou try this?

Comment: Made the change as you requested. But still the same problem. I am editing my questions with a screenshot of how the architect build section looks like in angular.json. Let me know if you catch something.

Comment: Hi David. I will tell you how my dist/main.js changes. In one of the source files, login.component.css, I have mentioned background-image: url("/assets/BG.png"); and during the build it got converted to background-image: url(\"/ATSTV2/assets/BG.png\"); in the dist/main.js. But in one source file, login.component.html I had, <img src="/assets/logo_White.png" alt="logo" id="logo-img">. This is the one that still remained the same without prefixing the ATSTV2. I think this is a code issue. Better ways to use img src???

Comment: Oh you are using angular universal, and your images are set in css directly?

Comment: ADREV2 is a typho. I meant to use ATSTV2

Comment: Have a look here: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/12093

Comment: What did you change in the end?

Answer (score 0):

make build with command

```
ng build --base-href="/ATSTV2/"
```

Comment: Hello Aakashgarg - Did as you said. But still the same problem

Comment: what is now assets path becoming on iis?

Comment: IIS Uses http://localhost/assets/Logo_White.png which is incorrect. The correct image link is http://localhost/ATSTV2/assets/Logo_White.png

Comment: try ng build --base-href /ATSTV2/

Comment: Hello Akash. Is this similar to your earlier command in the answer?

Comment: different syntax, picked it up from official doc. it should set correct path.

Comment: if the above doesn't work also try ng build --base-href="./"

Comment: @SARAVAN, did it help?

Comment: That did not help. Still the same behaviour