# angular routing not working in production

Tags: angular, routes

So guys the problem is like this. I have an angular project which is working just fine by running **ng serve**. But once I build it I can't access the routing paths just by writing them in the url like this **http://localhost/Angular/Damaskino2/dist/damaskino2/Admin**
but when I redirect to the site by clicking a button like this **<div id="bestellListe" *ngIf="!adminAussicht" routerLink="/Admin">**   And I get a not found response when I go to the url without navigating to it.

This is my html

````
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Damaskino2</title>
  <base href="/damaskino2/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <style type="text/css">@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:300;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v29/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmSU5fCRc4AMP6lbBP.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0460-052F, U+1C80-1C88, U+20B4, U+2DE0-2DFF, U+A640-A69F, U+FE2E-FE2F;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:300;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v29/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmSU5fABc4AMP6lbBP.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0400-045F, U+0490-0491, U+04B0-04B1, U+2116;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:300;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v29/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmSU5fCBc4AMP6lbBP.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+1F00-1FFF;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:300;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v29/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmSU5fBxc4AMP6lbBP.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0370-03FF;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:300;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v29/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmSU5fCxc4AMP6lbBP.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0102-0103, U+0110-0111, U+0128-0129, U+0168-0169, U+01A0-01A1, U+01AF-01B0, U+1EA0-1EF9, U+20AB;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:300;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v29/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmSU5fChc4AMP6lbBP.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:300;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v29/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmSU5fBBc4AMP6lQ.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:400;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v29/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu72xKKTU1Kvnz.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0460-052F, U+1C80-1C88, U+20B4, U+2DE0-2DFF, U+A640-A69F, U+FE2E-FE2F;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:400;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v29/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu5mxKKTU1Kvnz.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0400-045F, U+0490-0491, U+04B0-04B1, U+2116;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:400;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v29/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu7mxKKTU1Kvnz.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+1F00-1FFF;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:400;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v29/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu4WxKKTU1Kvnz.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0370-03FF;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:400;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v29/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu7WxKKTU1Kvnz.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0102-0103, U+0110-0111, U+0128-0129, U+0168-0169, U+01A0-01A1, U+01AF-01B0, U+1EA0-1EF9, U+20AB;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:400;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v29/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu7GxKKTU1Kvnz.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:400;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v29/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu4mxKKTU1Kg.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:500;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v29/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmEU9fCRc4AMP6lbBP.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0460-052F, U+1C80-1C88, U+20B4, U+2DE0-2DFF, U+A640-A69F, U+FE2E-FE2F;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:500;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v29/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmEU9fABc4AMP6lbBP.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0400-045F, U+0490-0491, U+04B0-04B1, U+2116;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:500;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v29/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmEU9fCBc4AMP6lbBP.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+1F00-1FFF;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:500;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v29/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmEU9fBxc4AMP6lbBP.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0370-03FF;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:500;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v29/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmEU9fCxc4AMP6lbBP.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0102-0103, U+0110-0111, U+0128-0129, U+0168-0169, U+01A0-01A1, U+01AF-01B0, U+1EA0-1EF9, U+20AB;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:500;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v29/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmEU9fChc4AMP6lbBP.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:500;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v29/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmEU9fBBc4AMP6lQ.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;}</style>
  <style type="text/css">@font-face{font-family:'Material Icons';font-style:normal;font-weight:400;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/materialicons/v125/flUhRq6tzZclQEJ-Vdg-IuiaDsNcIhQ8tQ.woff2) format('woff2');}.material-icons{font-family:'Material Icons';font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;font-size:24px;line-height:1;letter-spacing:normal;text-transform:none;display:inline-block;white-space:nowrap;word-wrap:normal;direction:ltr;-webkit-font-feature-settings:'liga';-webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;}</style>
<style>.mat-typography{font:400 14px/20px Roboto,Helvetica Neue,sans-serif;letter-spacing:normal}html,body{height:100%}body{margin:0;font-family:Roboto,Helvetica Neue,sans-serif}</style><link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.10a3678fc5e4410f.css" media="print" onload="this.media='all'"><noscript><link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.10a3678fc5e4410f.css"></noscript></head>
<body class="mat-typography">
  <app-root></app-root>
<script src="runtime.626e0c547591714e.js" type="module"></script><script src="polyfills.04fa8813fe852ba2.js" type="module"></script><script src="main.813f41971b458e52.js" type="module"></script>

</body></html>```


Now for the info it's not the base cause I have tried many thing and this is one of them that runs the site but the routing problem never changes
````

Comment: What url does it redirect to when you click the /admin button?

Comment: What server do you use for production?

Comment: Hi, I think you should look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69587942/angular-pwa-hosting-files-not-loading/69595231#69595231) to solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

For serving SPA you need to setup your server for return `index.html` for every requested route.

for example:

```
/*
  Incredibly simple Node.js and Express application server for serving static assets.
  
  DON'T USE THIS IN PRODUCTION!
    It is meant for learning purposes only. This server is not optimized for performance, 
    and is missing key features such as error pages, compression, and caching.
  
  For production, I recommend using an application framework that supports server-side rendering, 
    such as Next.js. https://nextjs.org
  Or, if you do indeed want a Single Page App, the Create React App deployment docs contain a lot 
    of hosting options. https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/ 
*/

const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
const app = express();

// serve static assets normally
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist'));

// handle every other route with index.html, which will contain
// a script tag to your application's JavaScript file(s).
app.get('*', function (request, response) {
  response.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'index.html'));
});

app.listen(port);
console.log("server started on port " + port);
```