# Angular: serve all build files from a subdirectory

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular15

I'm building an Angular 15 application and I'd like to have all the files served to the end user from a subdirectory rather than from the domain root. For example, what now is `GET http://example.com/main.js` should be `GET http://example.com/app/main.js`, while the application `index.html` would still be served from any location other than `http://example.com/app/**`.

It looks like the option I was looking for, `deployUrl` has been deprecated and I can't manage to achieve the desired scheme not even following [this detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51182322/whats-the-difference-between-base-href-and-deploy-url-parameters-of-angular/70575325#70575325) I found while searching around.

Trying to use both `baseHref` and `APP_BASE_HREF` causes the application to be served only from subpaths of `baseHref`, so, for example, setting `"baseHref": "/foo"` and the value provided to `APP_BASE_HREF` to `/bar/` leads to

`GET http://example.com/` not found 
`GET http://example.com/bar` not found 
`GET http://example.com/foo` remapped on the browser to `http://example.com/bar/foo`

Do you know if there is a way to achieve what I want using Angular only and not messing around with the webserver configuration?