Angular app deployed in non-root path of the Tomcat server failes to load resources
I have angular application packed in a war file and I deploy it on the tomcat server by url http://localhost:8080/webc/
The problem is that when trying to access the deployed app by the url http://localhost:8080/webc/index.html I see that some resources like js files were not loaded.
From the web browser console I see that they are requested by the wrong url like http://localhost:8080/polyfills-S3BTP7ME.js
The index.html is generated by the Angular and it includes the scripts like this:
<script src="polyfills-S3BTP7ME.js" type="module"></script>
How to make it load resource not from the domain root but from the correct deployment path?

You need to change the application base path:
Angular before 14:
ng build --prod --base-href /webc/
Angular from 14:
ng build --configuration production --base-href /webc/
https://stackoverflow.com/a/55666548/935330
