# How to fix fusion charts displaying black color in 3d charts on safari?

Tags: node.js, angular, safari, fusioncharts

I've implemented fusion charts in angular and node.js application. The charts appear black on safari but works fine with all other browsers.

I have researched and found out that it is something with the path of gradient colors because only 3D charts appear to not work properly. I have tried removing the base tag from main.html but that upsets my routing. Is there any other way I can fix this issue without disturbing my routing?

```
import { FusionChartsModule } from "angular-fusioncharts";
import FusionCharts from "fusioncharts/core";
import * as Candy from "fusioncharts/themes/fusioncharts.theme.candy";
import * as FusionTheme from "fusioncharts/themes/fusioncharts.theme.fusion";
import * as Gammel from "fusioncharts/themes/fusioncharts.theme.gammel";
import * as Umber from "fusioncharts/themes/fusioncharts.theme.umber";
import Doughtnut2d from "fusioncharts/viz/doughnut2d";
import MsArea from "fusioncharts/viz/msarea";
import MsBar3d from "fusioncharts/viz/msbar3d";
import MsColumn2d from "fusioncharts/viz/mscolumn2d";
import MsColumn3d from "fusioncharts/viz/mscolumn3d";
import MsColumnLine3d from "fusioncharts/viz/mscolumnline3d";
import MsLine from "fusioncharts/viz/msline";
import OverlappedCoulmn2d from "fusioncharts/viz/overlappedcolumn2d";
import Pie2d from "fusioncharts/viz/pie2d";
import Pie3d from "fusioncharts/viz/pie3d";
import StackedColumn2d from "fusioncharts/viz/stackedcolumn2d";
import StackedColumn3d from "fusioncharts/viz/stackedcolumn3d";

FusionChartsModule.fcRoot(
    FusionCharts,
    Pie2d,
    Pie3d,
    StackedColumn2d,
    OverlappedCoulmn2d,
    MsColumn2d,
    MsBar3d,
    MsColumn3d,
    Doughtnut2d,
    StackedColumn3d,
    MsLine,
    MsArea,
    MsColumnLine3d,
    Gammel,
    Candy,
    Umber,
    FusionTheme,
);
```

This is the way I am including Fusion Charts library into my application. If there is any options I can change to fix SVG paths.

Thank you!

Comment: After fcRoot statement use this line
FusionCharts.options['SVGDefinitionURL']= "absolute";

Comment: This only works on the first page loaded with charts. I have different routes where the charts are implemented, so if i go to another route the column charts are missing columns or if i go to doughnut charts the colours are not correct.

Comment: refer this post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25713345/fusioncharts-not-rendering-properly-when-base-tag-included-in-html-head