# Fusioncharts graphs are not rendering when the tab is not active - Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, charts, rendering, fusioncharts

**EDIT:**
Now I am getting the data properly by adding an *ngIf condition for graph component. But, the chart getting rendered, **not getting any fill color**. The fill URL getting is

[image]

```
fill="url('http://localhost:4200/#rr-1272-xr___89_110_110__rgba_118_193_134_0.9__78-rgba_118_193_134_0.9__89')"
```

**OLD:(Found solution)**
In my application, the Fusioncharts graphs are not rendering when the tab is not active. Even when the tab comes to active, the graphs are not rendering. Showing **No data to display** message as follows

[image]

HTML:

```
<section class="">
        <!-- fusion chart starts here -->
            <fusioncharts   width="220" height="220" type="doughnut2d"
                [dataSource]="dataSource" dataFormat="json" SVGDefinitionURL='absolute'>
            </fusioncharts>
        <!-- fusion chart ends here -->
</section>
```

Component:

```
let xyz = {
    chart: {
        "bgColor": "#ffffff",
        "startingAngle": "310",
        "showLegend": "0",
        "defaultCenterLabel": this.returnValue(this.chartData) + "\n" + "Total",
        // "centerLabel": "$value" + "\n" + "$label",
        "centerLabelBold": "0",
        "showTooltip": "0",
        "theme": "fusion",
        "minAngleForValue": "75",
        "enablesmartLabel": "0",
        "showLabels": "0",
        "showValues": "0",
        "enableMultiSlicing": "0",
        "showBorder": "0",
        "showPlotBorder": "1",
        "plotBorderColor": "#ffffff",
        "plotBorderThickness": "5",
        // "legendPosition": "RIGHT",
        "doughnutRadius": "70",
        "paletteColors": "#6C7DED,#3CA653,#FFAB27,#3AC9E9,#6C7DED,#0C8455,#FDCF12,#76E4FC",
        "animateClockwise": "0",
        "chartLeftMargin": "0",
        "chartRightMargin": "0",
        "chartTopMargin": "0",
        "chartBottomMargin": "0",
        "captionPadding": "0",
        "slicingDistance": "0",
        "plotHoverEffect": "1",
        "centerLabelFontSize": "20",
        "centerLabelFont": "DroidSans",
        "centerLabelColor": "#222222",
    },
    data: [
        {
            "label": "Pilot",
            "id": "Pilot",
            "value": 5,
            "color": "#3CA653",
            "link": "studies?studies-by-phase=Pilot"
        },
        {
            "label": "Pivotal",
            "id": "Pivotal",
            "value": 2,
            "color": "#FFAB27",
            "link": "studies?studies-by-phase=Pivotal"
        },
        {
            "label": "Phase 1",
            "id": "Phase 1",
            "value": 4,
            "color": "#3AC9E9",
            "link": "studies?studies-by-phase=Phase 1"
        },
        {
            "label": "Phase 2",
            "id": "Phase 2",
            "value": 3,
            "color": "#6C7DED",
            "link": "studies?studies-by-phase=Phase 2"
        }
    ]
};
this.dataSource = { ...xyz };
```

Please help me solve this issue.

Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

In the module.ts file add SVGDefinitionURL as absolute instead of adding in component.html

```
FusionCharts.options['SVGDefinitionURL'] = absolute;
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried that too. But, no luck.

Comment: Please refer the link - https://stackoverflow.com/a/55408986/7404858

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this whenever you reloading the page and switching it to the next tab, and then when the page reloads on revisiting the page the chart animates, because the viewport is not visible when you are on the other tab as soon as you open the tab containing the chart it comes to the active state and animates that way, if you dont want the chart to animate when you are revisiting the tab after refreshing kindly set animation attribute at the chart level to 0.

As explained here:

The issue is not primarily with FusionCharts - it is a generic SVG issue. In SVG, when gradient colour is applied on an element, it actually "refers" to another gradient element on the page. This is somewhat similar to how links can refer to hashtags using on a page.

Now, when you are setting a to the page, the references are going haywire. The gradients now refer to an element with URL as provided in your tag.

Use this code to fix -

```
FusionCharts.options.SVGDefinitionURL='absolute';
```